# Graph API: Check if app already posted in the past x days before creating a wall post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, stream, feed, facebook-wall

I would like to post to the user wall, but I want to limit the posts my app makes to max 1 per day or week.

Can I check how many posts my app made so far in the past day / week or do I need to store this on my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the [FQL `stream` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) by `app_id`.

Combine that with `source_id` (ID of user the wall belongs to) and `created_time` greater than 1 day / 1 week in the past, and `LIMIT 1`.

If you get a result, then there was a post made through your app in the specified time range.